# Escape delimiters

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

## Escape delimiters in Swift 5.

I am making a new iOS application with Swift 5.0, and I want to use delimiters for better code reusability, but I don't know about them. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5.0 Apple implemented a good concept of deliminators.
And to use them with interpolated string they introduced escaping delimiters.
It's very simple concept, according to swift evolution changelog documentation:

An escape delimiter in a string literal must match the number of pound signs used to delimit either end of the string.

Here is the degenerate case. It is a normal string with no pound signs. The escape delimiter therefore needs no pound signs and a single backslash is sufficient to establish the escape character sequence:

```
"This string has an \(interpolated) item"
```

Strings using custom boundary delimiters mirror their pound sign(s) after the leading backslash, as in these examples which produce identical results to the preceding string literal:

```
#"This string has an \#(interpolated) item"#

####"This string has an \####(interpolated) item"####
```

Source [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md)